# sql error on for xml removal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi we have a legacy code which we are trying to modify and trying to get rid of "for XML". the current code is as below

```
Select  
            a.columnidfk            as columnid,
            tvs.columnversion           as columnversion,
            a.newcolumnId               as newcolumnid,
                (Select
                    at.columnTrackingId     as columntrackingid,
                    at.newcolumnIdFk            as newcolumnid,
                    at.IDBSIdFk as idbid,
                    i.Name                      as iname,
                    IsNull(convert(varchar,at.colidbdate,101),'')       as colidbdate,
                    IsNull(convert(varchar,at.colidbdate2,101),'')  as colidbdate2,
                    IsNull(at.colReason, '')            as colReason,
                    IsNull(d.DispositionText, '')       as DispositionText,
                    at.status as status
                From columnTracking at
            Left Outer Join LkIDBs i on at.IDBSIdFk = i.IDBSId
            left outer join LkDisposition d On at.[colDecisionIdFk] = d.DispositionId
        Where at.status in('Active','Inactive')  and at.newcolumnIdFk = a.newcolumnId and (i.status in ('Active','Inactive') OR i.status is null) and (d.status='Active' or d.status is null) 
        for Xml path('columntracking'), type)
        From tablecolumns a             
        Left Outer Join columnVersions tvs on a.columnversionidfk = tvs.columnversionid Where 
        a.columnVersionIdFk in
        (Select columnVersionId From columnVersions tv
            Inner Join tabcolumns t On tv.colIdFk = t.colId 
            Where t.TicketNo = @TicketNo )
        order by a.TicketVersionIdFk , a.assessmentid
        For Xml path('columntab'), Root('columns')
```

when i remove the "**for Xml path('columntracking'), type**" and  "**For Xml path('columntab'),Root('columns')**" im getting the below error

**`Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`**

Please advise !

Comment: xml was parent node and children, if you remove for xml path, what do you want output as for the child element values, as error indicates, there will be multiple rows per on columntab. what is the use case behind removing for xml path, how is the output used? ..

Comment: `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH...` produces a string in XML format, one per row. Removing `FOR XML` and it will produce a table. So essentially you are trying to nest a table inside a row! That is invalid.

Comment: Your right I need the columns in table format rather than xml format. I tried to place the first xml output code in an left outer join to the parent code, but it seems to produce double the no of rows. is there any other way i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i got the desired table out by Joining the (first xml out put)

```
Select  
            a.columnidfk            as columnid,
            tvs.columnversion           as columnversion,
            a.newcolumnId               as newcolumnid,
            att.columntrackingid,
            att.newcolumnid,
            att.idbid,
            att.iname

        From tablecolumns a             
        Left Outer Join columnVersions tvs on a.columnversionidfk = tvs.columnversionid Where 
        left outer join (
        Select
                    at.columnTrackingId     as columntrackingid,
                    at.newcolumnIdFk            as newcolumnid,
                    at.IDBSIdFk as idbid,
                    i.Name                      as iname,
                    IsNull(convert(varchar,at.colidbdate,101),'')       as colidbdate,
                    IsNull(convert(varchar,at.colidbdate2,101),'')  as colidbdate2,
                    IsNull(at.colReason, '')            as colReason,
                    IsNull(d.DispositionText, '')       as DispositionText,
                    at.status as status
                From columnTracking at
            Left Outer Join LkIDBs i on at.IDBSIdFk = i.IDBSId
            left outer join LkDisposition d On at.[colDecisionIdFk] = d.DispositionId
        Where at.status in('Active','Inactive')  and (i.status in ('Active','Inactive') OR i.status is null) and (d.status='Active' or d.status is null) 
        ) att on att.newcolumnid = a.newcolumnId
        and a.columnVersionIdFk in
        (Select columnVersionId From columnVersions tv
            Inner Join tabcolumns t On tv.colIdFk = t.colId 
            Where t.TicketNo = @TicketNo )
```